# Only one array element is passed to my asynctask

Tags: android, string, arraylist, android-asynctask

I am trying to pass a simple string array to my asynctask but it's only passing one element.  I know my arraylist is populated with 20 elements before calling the asynctask, but when I check the size in the doinBackground it's only one.  I looked at some examples, questions and answers, quite similiar to mine, but it still only pass this one element.  Any help will be greatly appreciated...

```
new LoadImageTask().execute(tuxUrls); //tuxUrls has 20 elements
...

private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, ArrayList<Bitmap>> {

    private String name;
    Bitmap imageBitmap;
    ArrayList<TuxLoader> milTuxs = new ArrayList<TuxLoader>();


    @Override
    //protected ArrayList<TuxLoader> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... tuxUrls) {

        System.out.println("TuxUrlCount = " + tuxUrls.length);
        ArrayList<String> t = tuxUrls[0]; //thought I was passing entire array here

        try {
            for(int i=0; i<tuxUrls.length; i++) {

                URL imageUrl = new URL(t[i]);

                //do work


            }

              ...   

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", "Image Download Failed");
            }
          return milTuxs;
        }   


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TuxLoader> milTuxs) {
        super.onPostExecute(milTuxs);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //set the grid Adapter
                     ...
```

Comment: Is `tuxUrls` an array or an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Yes in doInBackground the parameter is `ArrayList<String>... tuxUrls` which means `ArrayList<String>[] tuxUrls`

Comment: @Skip, you loop through `tuxUrls`, and not **t**. I guess it was a typo in the code.

Comment: @Ali, yes it was a typo, t[] should be tuxUrls[].

Comment: @Ali, sorry it wasn't a typo, it's correct the way I had it. Do too many things at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> t = tuxUrls[0];

try {
    for(int i=0; i<t.size(); i++) {
        URL imageUrl = new URL(t.get(i));
        //do work
    }

          ...   

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", "Image Download Failed");
    }
return milTuxs;
```

The "ArrayList... tuxUrls" means that you can pass any number of "ArrayList" to this function, but since you pass only one, you have to choose the 1st element.

Comment: It still never worked.  I had to change t.length to t.size and t[i] t.get[i].  It still only gave one item.

Comment: I solved it.  The "The "ArrayList... tuxUrls" means that you can pass any number of "ArrayList" to this function" clicked for me.  Therefore I set URL imageURL = new UrL(tuxUrls[0].get(i)); and it worked.  I used asynctasks before but only to pass one or two elements which were separated by commas.  I've never done it like this before so the remainder of your statement makes perfect sense.  A thousand thanks to you because I was hung-up on this fora while!

Comment: Oops, sorry, I've made a typo in my example thinkg about simple array instead of ArrayList. Now it's fixed

Comment: that you for your input as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this,

```
 ArrayList<String> t = new ArrayList<String>();
 t.addAll(tuxUrls); //this will add the entire list to your t provided tuxUrls is also a list.
```

and then call each of them as

```
try {
        for(int i=0; i<t.length; i++) {

            URL imageUrl = new URL(t.get(i));

            //do work


    }
```

Comment: I get an error on t.addAll(tuxUrls) saying the (Collection<? extends String>) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>[])

Comment: Try setting it like ArrayList<String> t = tuxUrls[0]; as @nikis said.